# Is there a way to find the tone/sentiment of a phone conversation in Dutch language without translation?

Tags: dataset, artificial-intelligence, sentiment-analysis

Im working on a project that gets a Dutch phone conversation between a customer and an agent, converts it to text. I need to find if the tone/sentiment of the conversation was positive or negative. I cant seem to find any Dutch language datasets or pretrained models like NLTK for the Dutch language. Translating the text into English doesn't seem like a very optimal solution as it takes into account the inaccuracy of the translator as well. can someone please help me out if you have a labeled Dutch language dataset for sentimental analysis. Else is there a better way to find the tone/sentiment of the phone call? I have the .wav file of the calls as well.